# Generic BST not inserting all values and returning null

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement a generic binary search tree. I'm inserting 7 integers and want them to return with inOrder traversal however it's only returning 4 values out of order. Then I check if the tree contains a specific value but it always returns null and i'm unsure why. I'll post the code below, any idea's on why my output is what it is? I know my issues are probably within my insert and find methods, but unsure why, some clarification would be nice. Appreciate any advice, thanks!

Output when inserting integers 15, 10, 20, 5, 13, 11, 19:

```
run:
InOrder: 
Inorder traversal:  10 15 11 19 
Is 11 in the tree? null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Node.class:

```
class Node<E> {
  protected E element;
  protected Node<E> left;
  protected Node<E> right;

  public Node(E e) {
    element = e;
  }
}
```

BinarySearchTree.class:

```
class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> {
  private Node<E> root;

  public BinarySearchTree() {
    root = null;
  }

  public Node find(E e) {
    Node<E> current = root;

    while (e.compareTo(current.element) != 0) {
      if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
          current = current.left;
      }
      else {
          current = current.right;
      }
      if (current == null) {
          return null;
      }
    }
    return current;
  }

  public void insert(E e) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(e);

    if (root == null) {
        root = newNode;
    } else {
        Node<E> current = root;
        Node<E> parent = null;

        while (true) {
            parent = current;
            if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
                current = current.left;
            }
            if (current == null) {
                parent.left = newNode;
                return;
            } else {
                current = current.right;
                if (current == null) {
                    parent.right = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }

  public void traverse(int traverseType) {
    switch(traverseType) {
      case 1: System.out.print("\nPreorder traversal: ");
          preOrder(root);
          break;
      case 2: System.out.print("\nInorder traversal:  ");
          inOrder(root);
          break;
      case 3: System.out.print("\nPostorder traversal: ");
          postOrder(root);
          break;
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  private void inOrder(Node<E> localRoot) {
    if (localRoot != null) {
      inOrder(localRoot.left);
      System.out.print(localRoot.element + " ");
      inOrder(localRoot.right);
    }
  }

  private void preOrder(Node<E> localRoot) {
    if (localRoot != null) {
      System.out.print(localRoot.element + " ");
      preOrder(localRoot.left);
      preOrder(localRoot.right);
    }
  }

  private void postOrder(Node<E> localRoot) {
    if (localRoot != null) {
      postOrder(localRoot.left);
      postOrder(localRoot.right);
      System.out.print(localRoot.element + " ");
    }
  }

}
```

Main class:

```
public class BST_Test{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    testInteger();
  }

  static void testInteger() {
    BinarySearchTree<Integer> itree = new BinarySearchTree<>();
    itree.insert(15);
    itree.insert(10);
    itree.insert(20);
    itree.insert(5);
    itree.insert(13);
    itree.insert(11);
    itree.insert(19);

    // Traverse tree
    System.out.print("InOrder: ");
    itree.traverse(2);

    // Search for an element
    System.out.println("Is 11 in the tree? " + itree.find(11));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is your poorly formatted code is hiding the fact your `insert` method is incorrect.

This `if` statement does not have an opening curly brace `{` (and subsequently the closing curly brace `}` since it compiles), so as a result only the subsequent statement is included in this `if` block:

```
if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0)
    current = current.left
```

This means the following is executed regardless of whether the condition above is true...

```
if (current == null) {
    parent.left = newNode;
    return;
} ...
```

... and as a result if `current != null`, your insertion will then proceed to the right:

```
... else {
    current = current.right;
    if (current == null) {
        parent.right = newNode;
        return;
    }
}
```

---

In full your *current **erroneous*** code, when formatted/indented appropriately is:

```
public void insert(E e) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(e);

    if (root == null) {
        root = newNode;
    } else {
        Node<E> current = root;
        Node<E> parent = null;

        while (true) {
            parent = current;
            if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0) // missing { ...
                current = current.left; // ... so only this is in the if block

            if (current == null) {
                parent.left = newNode;
                return;
            } else { // oops, this should be else to the e.compareTo(current.element) < 0 condition
                current = current.right;
                if (current == null) {
                    parent.right = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Fixed** code (assuming duplicates are allowed):

```
public void insert(E e) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(e);

    if (root == null) {
        root = newNode;
    } else {
        Node<E> current = root;
        Node<E> parent = null;

        while (true) {
            parent = current;
            if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
                current = current.left;
                if (current == null) {
                    parent.left = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                current = current.right;
                if (current == null) {
                    parent.right = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Moral of the story: Keeping your code well-formatted and using curly braces for blocks will save you headaches.

Comment: Yeah I edited the insert method to the exact same code as you have, however the output is exactly the same.

Comment: Nevermind, one bracket in the wrong place. I'll definitely reformat this. Thanks!